# The type org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("abcde").password("123456").roles("USER");   
}
```

and i am getting an error in the last line, it says that

```
The type org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have looked for a solution and cannot find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add spring-security-core.jar to the Build Path of the project. If you are using Eclipse, right click on project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> click Add jars or Add external jars and point to the jar file.

Also, do clean build.

Answer (score 9):

Add spring-security-core to your build path.
If you already have one, download the latest version.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

after **mvn clean install** ,  if you still see error in eclipse. refresh the project.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had spent 3 hours to figure out to fix this issue.

### 1st fix

Check the pom.XML file has appropriate dependencies like below. For spring boot security the mandatory dependencies are mentioned below. 
**Note: do not confuse between "spring web" and "spring boot web" dependencies.** It has to be "spring boot web" dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

### 2nd fix

If you tried different versions of spring security for testing purpose within the project those traces contradicts at the time of compilation for picking the right version of jar files. (Ignore this sentence if you don't understand). Simply follow the below instructions to fix the problem.

- Go to your IDE's repository .m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\
- Go to IDE's project properties -> maven -> update project
- Go to IDE menu "project" -> clean. ( that's it )
- Now run the project as "Spring boot Application". (First you have to stop the server if it is running in the background)`enter code here`

I had followed the above steps and able to fix my issue. I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: This one, <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency> did the trick

Answer (score 1):

1. navigate to the directory structure of your own:

   C:\Users\Administrator.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\4.1.1.RELEASE
2. delete the 4.1.1.RELEASE directory
3. right click on the project --> maven --> update project
4. clean --> rebuild project

Answer (score -1):

If you use gradle, it's more easy check if you have these libraries ... compile

- spring-security-web
- spring-security-config
- spring-security-taglibs
- spring-security-ldap
- spring-boot-starter-ws
- spring-security-core